# VS 2015 cannot detect git file update (path too long)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Problem:

VS 2015 cannot do a merge from bitbucket. The error shows:

An error occurred. Detailed message: invalid path '\?\C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-quickconnect\node_modules\browserify-middleware\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack\node_modules\combine-source-map\node_modules\convert-source-map\test\fixtures\xxxxxxxx.css' (path too long)

Comment: I got the solution: move folder to C:/repo/xxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Windows API generally limits the lengths of paths to a maximum of 260 characters, which means that unfortunately there isn't much you can do.

If you want to access a path with greater than 260 characters it has to be prefixed with `\\?\` to enable long path support, so if you are able to change the path that it uses that may fix the problem (but not all Windows API calls support extended paths).